# Handlebars nested each with same variable names

Tags: javascript, html, nested, handlebars.js, each

I have an object i use with handlebars template and it has a sub array of objects and those objects also have member variables that have same names as the parent object members. Something like this:

```
{  
   "objects":[  
      {  
         "member":"meander",
         "subObjects":[  
            {  
               "member":"salamander"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

{{#each objects}}
  <span>{{member}}</span>
  {{#each subObjects}}
    <span>{{member}}</span>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

This results in the inner `member` referring to the parent's `member` variable and prints

> meander

instead of

> salamander

How can i make it so it refers to the inner one?

Comment: I see {{#each objects}} in your template, but there is not objects in the json.
Can you, please, clarify this?

Comment: How about binding the context with `this`?

Comment: My bad. this context is already bound in an upper level @JohnKennedy

Comment: Are you using an old version of Handlebars? Handlebars _does_ scope the inner `{{#each}}` to the `subObjects` object. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/usz2oyxz/